# Extending emacs-lisp syntax

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am interested in extending the syntax in emacs-lisp, but I have not found any hints anywhere about the feasibility of this or how to achieve it. I want to try some things that are illustrated [here](http://readable.sourceforge.net), so that in Emacs, for example, I could type `{1 + 2 + 3}` and have it interpreted in a program as `(+ 1 2 3)`. I am familiar with some projects to use syntax like `($ 1 + 2 + 3)` for this purpose, but I want to try modifying the syntax, not create a new infix function like that.

I did find some documentation on changing syntax tables, but this seems to be more for the editor, and not the lisp parser.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Emacs [reader](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Printed-Representation.html) is not as flexible as [that](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_b.htm) of Common Lisp, so you cannot make it read `{a + b + c}` as `(+ a b c)`.

Moreover, the experience has shown that doing so is a waste of time: no one ever writes Lisp like that; projects like "readable" you quoted remain a curious demonstration of CL's power rather than something actually usable.

Comment: If I didn't have a good reason for it I wouldn't bother! If we want to use a Lisp for solving mathematical problems, the infix notation would be much easier to read for some parts of the code. Compare these:

    (defun func (Ca)
      "Objective function: Fa0 - Fa + V * ra"
      (let ((ra (* (* -1 k) Ca))
     (Fa (* v0 Ca))))
      (+ (- Fa0 Fa) (* ra V)))

vs.

(defun func (Ca)
  "Objective function: Fa0 - Fa + V * ra"
  (let ((ra {-k * Ca})
        (Fa {v0 * Ca})
    {Fa0 - Fa + V * ra})))

I guess that doesn't show too well, and a macro would work ;)